# TikZ node minimum width/height cannot be smaller than a specific value

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I use `node` to draw rectangle with `[shape=rectangle]`, I set `minimum width=1pt`, then I find that the result is not what I expect.

It seems that the `minimum width/height` of a node cannot be smaller than some value (about `7pt` in this case, I do not test other cases).

And the `\path [...] (...) rectangle (...);` works with no problem.

Here is a minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]

\path[clip] (0, 0) rectangle (30, 20);

% left-top rect with `rectangle`
\path [draw=black, fill=gray] (10,10) rectangle (17,17);
% unit rect with `rectangle`
\fill [draw=yellow, fill=cyan] (13,13) rectangle (14,14);
% bottom rect with `node shape`
\node [draw=green, fill=blue, shape=rectangle, minimum width=1pt, minimum height=1pt, anchor=north west] at (10,10) {};
% right rect with `node shape`
\node [draw=blue, fill=green, shape=rectangle, minimum width=1pt, minimum height=1pt, anchor=south west] at (17,10) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to set the space around the text to zero with `inner sep=0pt`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob It works perfectly. Thanks a lot! I get the default value of  `inner sep` with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}`, I find that it is `.3333em`, since `1em=12pt`, this means the default `inner sep` is `4pt`, and a rectangle has two sides, which occupies `4pt * 2 = 8pt`, so this explains why the "specified value" in my case is about `7pt`.

Comment: @Hansimov, you could answer your own question with the text in the comment above, and then select it as the correct answer.